# Entity Framework Code first configure one-to-many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

i'm starting to use and get familiar with entity code first relationship

> http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

I'm having difficulties in translating the following situation to code first using EntityTypeConfiguration

Tables

```
Family( Id pk int,
        Name nvarchar)
Child( Id pk int, 
       FamilyId NULL constraint FK_Child_Family FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Family (Id) DEFAULT NULL)
```

Classes

```
class Family
{
     prop Id;
     prop Name;
}

class Child
{
     prop Id;

     prop FamilyId;
     virtual prop Family
}
```

I have this configuration for the Family

```
private void Configure(EntityTypeConfiguration<Family> entity)
        {
            entity.ToTable(nameof(Family));

            entity.HasKey(key => key.Id).Property(key => key.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None); ///--> primary key configuration

            entity.Property(prop => prop.Name).IsRequired();
        }
```

And i'm trying to achieve the following

Family does not know about Child

Child knows about Family and has a FamilyId (FK)

This is what i have so far for Child configuration

```
private void Configure(EntityTypeConfiguration<Child> entity)
        {
             ///--> only Child contains a Family FK 
             ///--> need to map to FamilyId
             ///--> want to specify name of FK : "FK_Child_Family"
           entity.HasOptional(user => user.Family) .... ? 

        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Seems like more on a one-to-many situation. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: EF has no support for this.